Next.js project was not deployed in Vercel, but it was built correctly in local
I have some problems to deploy Next.js project in Vercel. The project was built in local env.
I'm using Node version 18.0.0 in local env and also chose 18.x in Vercel env.
enter image description here
This image is what I got error in Vercel.
enter image description here
I tried to install puppeteer and deployed again in Vercel but it was not working.

Can you edit this post with more information, such as code snippets, repo link, or anything that can guide us to help you out?
